# htmlpurifier add missing url protocol

Tags: htmlpurifier

using AutoFormat.Linkify HTMLpurifier converts text such as `http://www.example.com into`  links.
But many people write links without the protocol, such as `www.example.com` or `example.com`. Is there anyway to use HTMLpurifier to also convert these into  links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know no way to get HTMLpurifier do this. But you should get this work by adding `http://` to every link, that does not containing it. you can use a regular expression to do this.

```
preg_replace( '#\s((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})\s#', 
              ' http://${3}.${4} ', $html );
```

Test the regex [here](http://regexr.com/391sr).

**Example:**

```
test example.com test<br>
test www.example.com test<br>
test http://example.com test
```

becomes

```
test http://example.com test
test http://www.example.com test
test http://example.com test
```

Now HTMLpurifier should do the right things.

Comment: Thanks. But if I a very long piece of text, an article for example, or a blog post, then wouldn't this not be a good idea?

Comment: because of the running time? I think this should not be a problem. I use this way to make my php code better documentable by doxygen. so the regex runs on 10000 lines of code in about two seconds. the best would be to run a performance test with data you expect as input.